# Can I continuously run cron jobs for magento if I am using windows?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cron, windows

What I am trying to do is to make cron jobs run automatically, for example I got more jobs, and when I hit www.mylink.com/cron.php, it executes the cron jobs once, and after that I have to press the refresh button or go again to that site in order to execute the cron job again. Is there a way to do that on windows automatically? Thanks for your help.

Comment: windows has schedular concept look for that

Comment: Have a look at this one here http://purusothaman.me/computers/running-cron-in-windows

Comment: @Klettseb I tried that tutorial it created the task but it won't work, it's not running the cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is late, but I found the answer with your help from the comments. I created a task to open access that link every minute. This tutorial helped me figure it out how to do that.  purusothaman.me/computers/running-cron-in-windows . Hope it will help someone.